# Axis2 : When to use Wsdd file with Axis2 Webservices

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I am using Axis2 for developing webservices .

I started from WSDL file , and used WSDL2Java  command line and generated all the sever related  code (Skeltons) , wrote services.xml file ,  modified the skelton ( Implemented business logic in it ) and deployed as .aar file inside the Services folder of Axis2.war .

Now my question is 
I have seen some examples using .wsdd file with Axis2 Webservices , i am really confused with this , please tell me  do we need .wsdd file ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Axis2 uses services.xml as the descriptor file.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have .wsdd files with Axis2 - its been used in Axis..

Answer (score 1):

In Axis 1 we use wsdd file. While in Axis2 we use services.xml or sun-jaxws.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want .wsdd file in Axis2 , To understand the migration from Axis 1.x to Axis2 and the improvements in Axis2 in comparison with Axis1 visit Apache Axis article : https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/migration.html